# How can I tell webdriver-io to use firefox developer edition?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, firefox, webdriver-io

How can I tell webdriver-io to use firefox developer edition instead of normal firefox? I need to use CSS4 selectors which normal firefox does not support. I read the documentation but I can not find the option.

Comment: Solution: Use Safari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redefine the location of Firefox by either setting set the `binary` capability:

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox',
        firefox_binary: 'C:\\...\\firefox.exe'
    }
};
```

Or by starting the standalone server with a new binary path:

```
java -jar "selenium-server-standalone-x.x.x.jar" -Dwebdriver.firefox.bin="C:\...\firefox.exe"
```

Comment: Second way tries to launch but crashes

Comment: My bad, it was `firefox_binary` instead of `binary`. Note that the latest dev version is probably not yet compatible with the driver.

Answer (score 0):

Florent, thanks for answer, I used it to test my application with **Firefox Quantum**.
I used Firefox Developer Version, which already contains Firefox Quantum Beta 14, and added in my BrowserFactory Class:

```
            else if (browserName.equals ("quantum") {
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        System.setProperty ("webdriver.gecko.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/geckodriver.exe");
        System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.DRIVER_USE_MARIONETTE,"true");
        System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE,javaIoTmpDir+"\\geckodriverlogs.txt");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\Portable\\FirefoxPortableDeveloper\\App\\Firefox64\\firefox.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```