# How to do automation testing of your website on firefox ? (webdriverio)

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am new to automation testing. I followed the steps given on "http://webdriver.io/guide.html" everything went great .
I installed 
node.js
selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3
geckodriver
chromeriver

My script goes like this:

```
var webdriverio = require(.\\webdriverio');
     var options = {
       desiredCapabilities: {
       browserName: 'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox'
     }
 };

 webdriverio
   .remote(options)
   .init()
   .url('http://www.google.com')
   .getTitle().then(function(title) {
    console.log('Title was: ' + title);
 })
 .end()
 .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
 });
```

This works well but it opens chrome browser where as I want to open firefox.

Comment: Isn’t it browserName be just firefox? You have given path. Guess this is not right.

Comment: In that case it gives error. I have tried it as well.

Error : 
type: 'SessionNotCreatedException',
   message: 'A new session could not be created.',

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: type: 'SessionNotCreatedException',
 message: 'A new session could not be created.',
Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService

Comment: Looks like GeckoDriver is either not latest or not in the path. Selenium is failing to locate it. May be u need explicitly set the System property to path of the driver.

Comment: May be this link will help https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4962

Comment: Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36878324/6849366

Comment: No Luck :( @MichaelHirschler

Comment: that guide uses outdated version of geckodriver and selenium.

Comment: Looks like you need to go back and reread and follow the instructions. Your code is not the same as the guide... start there.

Comment: I checked , could not find difference

Answer (score 0):

Switch browserName: 'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox'
to just browserName: 'firefox'